# UITableView cell rearranging array trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutableorderedset

i have a UITableView that a user can add and rearrange objects in... when the user moves an item, i try to re-arrange the data array to fit what the user has changed his cell order to... i am obviously not doing it correctly... here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSMutableOrderedSet *temp = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc]init];
    if(fromIndexPath.row == toIndexPath.row){
        temp = _dataArray;
    }
    int min,max;
    if(fromIndexPath.row > toIndexPath.row){min = toIndexPath.row;max = fromIndexPath.row;}
    if(fromIndexPath.row < toIndexPath.row){max = toIndexPath.row;min = fromIndexPath.row;}
    for(int i = 0; i < _dataArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%i",i);
        if(i == toIndexPath.row)
        {
            [temp insertObject:_dataArray[fromIndexPath.row] atIndex:i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(i >= min && i <= max)
            {
                if(fromIndexPath.row > toIndexPath.row)
                {
                    [temp insertObject:_dataArray[i] atIndex:i+1];
                }
                else if(fromIndexPath.row < toIndexPath.row)
                {
                    [temp insertObject:_dataArray[i] atIndex:i-1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                [temp insertObject:_dataArray[i] atIndex:i];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"================ Cell Array Testing ================");
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cell: %@",temp[i]);
    }
    _dataArray = temp;
}
```

Comment: Check out the [–exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableOrderedSet/exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:) method of `NSMutableOrderedSet`. Or just use `NSMutableArray` which has it too.

Comment: @Adam... The problem is that the entire order of the array shifts when one item in the table view moves... Like items all get shifted up or down